# Alignment issues in layout - Wordpress CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, alignment, twenty-twenty-three-theme

Somewhere along making edits, the layout of this page has ended up with the boxes mis-aligned - https://canons.com/our-products-bespoke-services/

Any advice/help on how to fix this is appreciated. Thank you.

Tried re-adjusting the padding between images but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide any code, I'm not sure what exactly the issue is. But from inspecting on your website, I see that these picture boxes are grouped per column by a `div` with the class name of `wp-block-columns` and you're using flexbox on it. So I'm guessing that the CSS code look something like:

```css
.wp-block-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

So I guess what you can do is to apply `flex-basis` to its children such as:

```css
.wp-block-columns > * {
    flex-basis: 100%
}
```

This means that all the children of `.wp-block-columns` will be divided evenly, so it should align your picture boxes.